# Right way of requesting permissions for location coordinates in Android 10

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, android-fusedlocation, android-11

Below code does not work on Android 10 until you manually enable the location from settings. When I go through the Android 10 documentation, it says if you are fetching location from the visible activity, if that was the case you don't need any foreground service, that's the reason I haven't used any service here.

And also as per Android 10 guidelines, after permission getting granted I am calling getLastLocation function.

Implementation is like, on main activity I am fetching location coordinates.
Please help, where in the code am I going wrong?

MainActivity.java

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import java.util.Locale;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;

    
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    protected Location mLastLocation;

    private String mLatitudeLabel;
    private String mLongitudeLabel;
    private TextView mLatitudeText;
    private TextView mLongitudeText;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        mLatitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.latitude_label);
        mLongitudeLabel = getResources().getString(R.string.longitude_label);
        mLatitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.latitude_text));
        mLongitudeText = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.longitude_text));

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        } else {
            getLastLocation();
        }
    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void getLastLocation() {

        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                            mLastLocation = task.getResult();
                            Log.d("raviraj", "lat is  " +mLastLocation.getLatitude());
                            Log.d("raviraj", "long is " +mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                            mLatitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                    mLatitudeLabel,
                                    mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
                            mLongitudeText.setText(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s: %f",
                                    mLongitudeLabel,
                                    mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                        } else {
                            Log.w("RAVIRAJ", "getLastLocation:exception" +task.getException());
                            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_location_detected));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    
    private void showSnackbar(final String text) {
        View container = findViewById(R.id.main_activity_container);
        if (container != null) {
            Snackbar.make(container, text, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    
    private void showSnackbar(final int mainTextStringId, final int actionStringId,
                              View.OnClickListener listener) {
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                getString(mainTextStringId),
                Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                .setAction(getString(actionStringId), listener).show();
    }

    
    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void startLocationPermissionRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            startLocationPermissionRequest();
                        }
                    });

        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            
            startLocationPermissionRequest();
        }
    }

    
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // If user interaction was interrupted, the permission request is cancelled and you
                // receive empty arrays.
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission granted.
                getLastLocation();
            } else {
                
                showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.location.sample.basiclocationsample" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Base" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NewMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there is a problem. Official documentation states that it can be null in some cases

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

1. Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be null even if the last location was previously retrieved because disabling location also clears the cache.
2. The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings.
3. Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location after the services restarted. To avoid this situation you can create a new client and request location updates yourself. For more information, see Receiving Location Updates.

In your case you can get location only if GPS is ON. Even for last known location.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current#last-known

Answer (score 0):

Please add this permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and add this to application tag

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` has to do with location?  I don't understand how your answer solves the problem.